# ExcelDna NuGet, "ExcelDna.AddIn.Targets" file building through msbuild returns error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, excel-dna

I'm using ExcelDna-AddIn NuGet Package in my Visual studios, When I try to build my class library project through visual studios it works fine while if i try to build it through msbuild(ExcelDna.AddIn.targets) i am getting '"CleanExcelAddIn" task was not given a value for the required parameter "OutDirectory" exited with code 1'

Comment: Looks like something is missing in your `.csproj`. Add `/v:diag` to the MSBuild invocation args and it will give you some additional info that can help figure out what's making the `$(OutDir)` parameter to be `null`. Also, Can you reproduce this error with a brand new class library (File -> New Project)?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I had created a new class library, still got the same error. Though, now I gave  'msbuild "project_name.targets" /p:configuration=release /p:OutDir=bin\' and got a successful build. (Included /p:OutDir=bin\). But didn't figure out why $(OutDir) parameter was showing null.

Comment: Just as Caio answered, the property of OutDir is defined in the  Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets file, you can find this file at: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin (VS2015). So if you want to build your .targets file without project file, you should add this property in your command, otherwise, you should add that target file in to you .target file.

Answer (score 1):

> I had created a new class library, still got the same error. Though,
>   now I gave 'msbuild "project_name.targets" /p:configuration=release
>   /p:OutDir=bin\' and got a successful build.

Based on your comment, it seems you're running MSBuild on a custom .targets file, and not a standard .csproj created by Visual Studio. `OutDir` is a property created by `Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets` which I'm guessing you're not including in your custom MSBuild file.